# Activator.CreateInstance alternatives for code optimization

Tags: c#, generics, optimization, reflection

I'm working on  generic forms and I use some reflection in the parent forms to handle some tasks. I want do some performance fix if possible, so any help is very appreciated.

below is what I call a BrowseForm

[image]

I have the following property on the parent form:

```
public string CrudName {get;set;}
```

I set the string name of the Crud form to open at design time, from the property grid of the Browse Form.

finally at runtime when the user clicks on Add New, Edit or Watch buttons I run the below code to open the new form and bind data to it

```
Type type = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
                .DefinedTypes
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == MyCrudName);


Form MyForm = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Base4Crud;
//some code here
MyForm.ShowDialog();
```

so I was wondering if it is possible to achieve the job in a better way. Thanks In advance

Comment: Reflection comes with inherent performance issues.  If you only have a set number of types then a simple if or case statement would be a lot quicker.  That said, if you're not seeing any performance issues then I'd just leave it.

Comment: What do you mean with *"better"*?

Comment: Why not instantiate the specific form object in the button click event handlers? There does not seem to be any need to use reflection here.

Comment: Oh wait: why the `FirstOrDefault`?, that's going to be an issue. Make it explicit which one you want.

Comment: Get the desired `ConstructorInfo` from the `Type` instance. Create a delegate using it and reuse that delegate. On the second call the runtime will be like a direct call.

Comment: You can improve this by searching the entry assembly only once at startup. Search for `Form` types only and cache the found form names and types in a dictionary.